# Delaying System.gc() in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

As far as I understand the documentation of `System.gc()` this call will point the GC towards regions of memory that the caller was ‘working’ on. There’s no guarantee for any clean up whatsoever happening after the method returns.

But say there was now obsolet data and the GC ‘decided’ to free the memory used by that data. Does this mean the freeing happened **before** the method returns? And if yes, is there a way to delay the freeing of memory itself? Would it make sense?

Say the statement above is true;
I am aware that simply delegating the call of `System.gc()` to another thread would make no sense following the logic implied by the documentation.
Would it on the other hand make sense to delegate references of obsolet data to another thread while simultaneously voiding the previous references anywhere else and then calling the GC on that thread?

For instance; say a singleton thread instance acts as a consumer and it simply consumes objects.

```
public static void consumeForGC(Object… args)
```

The objects are passed by reference which should (must?!) hinder the GC from freeing their allocated memory space. So when now calling the GC in the scope of this `consumeForGC(…)` in which the last known references to the given arguments are, does this achieve similar behavior to simply calling it (preferably at the end) of a caller and waiting for the call to return? Besides being very hacky, it would probably only increase the chances for some allocations to be released sooner, but at least it could give some control over which those are. The rest of the program could also carry on because it doesn’t have to wait for the GC to finish whatever it will actually do.

I hope this question is not too irrelevant nonetheless I am curious to hear what you guys think about this

Comment: "is there a way to delay the freeing of memory itself? Would it make sense?" what do you think it would achieve?

Comment: Essentially: no, it doesn't really make sense, because memory has to be unreachable if it is eligible for GC. So, it's unreachable (and thus unusable) whether you free it immediately or later; why do it later?

Comment: You misunderstand how garbage collection works and what the `System.gc()`call actually does. The actual garbage collector works independently of your application. Your application cannot really influence the GC except by not creating garbage. The `System.gc()`call tells the GC that **YOU** think it's a great time for a garbage collection. The GC might think otherwise. The actual collection will not be performed during the `System.gc()` call.

Comment: Also, it has nothing to do with things the caller has been "working" on. It will garbage-collect the entire JVM.

Comment: @Erik I think your last sentence is incorrect. The documentation says "Runs the garbage collector. Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse. **When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort to reclaim space from all discarded objects**. " (emphasis mine)

Comment: @RealSkeptic this is exactly what I was referring to but Erik is also correct, I read the doc again and I now understand that it will make a general effort of cleaning up. So instead of passing any objects (which I now understand doesn't have any effect) calling the GC on another thread would simply set the pace for the times the GC wakes up to do it's magic work. Correct?

Comment: @AndyTurner I meant delaying as in delegating the call to another thread, enabling the calling thread to carry on, knowing someone else will take care of the garbage it produced. Like party guests on a party, you know

Comment: I'm not sure why you are asking this. Just from curiosity? The `System.gc()` call is meant mostly for testing and debugging. The generally accepted practice is to let the garbage collect decide for itself when to do the collection based on the memory pressure.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes purely from curiosity. It's also just a theoretical approach and I found a bunch of articles suggesting gc tuning as a far better solution.

Comment: @RealSkeptic And the first part of the JavaDoc is "Calling this method **suggests** " and this is in fact what really happens. There is literally no guarantee that the GC will actually do anything under the call. I've tried invoking the `System.gc()` to force a gc to no avail. Looking at the actual behaviour shows that most of the time nothing happens and this is the important part. There are no guarantees that the gc will actually run. For one thing, it's not really clear what the gc should actually do. Scavenge?  Full GC? StW gc? Compacting?

Comment: @Erik of course there is no guarantee, but if it does anything, it will be done before the method returns. It's not like the method just marks for a gc and it can happen 15 minutes later.

Comment: There is no point in calling `System.gc()` from another thread. Either, you have stop-the-world collector which will stop *all* threads anyway or you have a concurrent collector which can run concurrently to the application threads and will most likely already be running, because it has much lower thresholds. In the latter case, just not calling `System.gc()` is the simpler solution. In fact, not calling `System.gc()` is always the simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understand the documentation of System.gc() this call will point the GC towards regions of memory that the caller was ‘working’ on.

It does not really "point towards memory". Rather invoking `System.gc()` can trigger a GC cycle that will run with somewhat different parameters compared to those automatically triggered by memory pressure or (in some concurrent collectors) background timers.

A GC cycle is always application-global, cleaning up some or all of the objects that are deemed unreachable from GC roots.

As a rule of thumb one shouldn't trigger `System.gc` without analysis of GC logs and application profiling to identify whether doing so improves some metrics. Used incorrectly it'll lead to excessive CPU consumption, decreased throughput and increased latency.

> There’s no guarantee for any clean up whatsoever happening after the method returns.

The specification is vague, in practice it depends on the JVM, selected garbage collector and config flags. E.g. on hotspot there are flags `DisableExplicitGC`, `ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent` and several other flags controlling its behavior.

But changing these parameters can impact other parts of the system, e.g. direct ByteBuffer allocations can resort to calling System.gc to trigger reclamation of unused buffers. If manual GCing is disabled or insufficiently aggressive it could lead to OOMEs when allocating direct buffers.

> Does this mean the freeing happened before the method returns? And if yes, is there a way to delay the freeing of memory itself? Would it make sense?

It does not promise to clean any specific objects, or any objects at all for the matter. But if it does trigger a GC then it'll only return once that cycle is complete, but that does not guarantee that all unreachable objects have been collected.